# Always make the DataGridView accept data only in the first row

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to insert a row only in the first position of datagridview and the added rows should move down.

I am using the following code

```
DataRow row = dtLocl.NewRow();
dtLocl.Rows.InsertAt(row,0);
```

when a new record is added I am unable to set the focus.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/080e68a3-2bcd-4c1d-ae60-54b43b9c040e/) link will help you..

EDIT: forget the link.. try this:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Selected = true;
```

Comment: That article suggested using the CurrentCell property and the OP wants the focus on the *first* row, not the last.

Comment: I am inserting a new blank row at starting position of datagridview,
when I write any text in that cell and press Tab at that time i am checking that text in rowvalidating event.If it is not blank then I will insert one more blank row at starting position,but now I am not able to focus at the starting position.I tried 
 DataRow row = dtLocl.NewRow();
                    dtLocl.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
dgDepartment.CurrentCell = dgDepartment[2, 0];
                    dgDepartment.Rows[0].Selected = true;

But it is focusing on the second row of datagridview not in Blank row

Comment: I am not getting Focus method with datagridview in intellisense